# input disabled js

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, устанавливается chek даже если `input disabled`.
Как сделать что бы check не устанавливался если `input disabled`?

```js
function check(number) {
  document.getElementById('stol['+number+']').checked = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="stoli" name="stol" id="stol[1]" >
<input type="radio" class="stoli" name="stol" id="stol[2]" disabled><br>
<a onclick="check(2)">Check</a>
```

Comment: Атрибут `disabled` предназначен для _**пользователей**_. На действие JS скриптов он никак не влияет.

Comment: Как вариант, проверять наличие `disabled`. Если элемент `disabled`, то не устанавливать `checked = true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойства `disabled` и `checked` принимают значения `true` или `false`.

Но если `.disabled` - `false`, `.checked` должен стать `true`, и наоборот. Поэтому функцию можно переписать так:

```
function check(number) {
  let elem = document.getElementById('stol[' + number + ']');
  elem.checked = !elem.disabled;
}

// !false → true
// !true → false
```

Если бы там был другой код помимо изменения checked, можно было так:

```
function check(number) {
  let elem = document.getElementById('stol[' + number + ']');
  if (elem.disabled) return; // Если disabled - true, выполнение прервется (return)

  elem.checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Путём проверки на disabled:

```js
function check(number) {
  let input = document.getElementById('stol['+number+']');
  if(!input.hasAttribute('disabled')) {
    input.checked = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="stoli" name="stol" id="stol[1]" >
<input type="radio" class="stoli" name="stol" id="stol[2]" disabled><br>
<a onclick="check(2)">Check</a>
```